# Any way to handle errors on symfony without using twig?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a JSON API right now using FOSRestBundle. I'm having some trouble dealing with errors outside my API's routing spacing because Symfony seems hell-bent on requiring Twig in order to capture `HttpException`, and I obviously have no use for twig other than on the dev controller (for the web debug tools).

The end result is that I'm getting 500 errors when I try to access any resources not being handled by routing, instead of a 404, when using the prod controller. This is unsightly. Proper http codes are given back when using the dev controller, as Twig is active on it.

How can I tap into symfony to handle errors my way without requiring Twig enabled on production, short of catching exceptions on the prod controller?

Comment: Probably want to add your own exception listener: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! If I understand your use-case correctly, you can create a custom exception controller:

1. Redefine the `twig.controller.exception.class` parameter
2. Create a custom controller

Here's an example from one of my projects:

In `app/config/services.yml` or wherever is appropriate for your project, add:

```
parameters:
    twig.controller.exception.class: AppBundle\Controller\ExceptionController
```

Then create custom controller `src/AppBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php`:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController as BaseExceptionController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;

/**
 * ExceptionController
 *
 * Override standard exceptions
 * in production env with basic
 * json response codes.
 *
 * @see app/config/services.yml
 */
class ExceptionController extends BaseExceptionController
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        if ($request->attributes->get('showException', $this->debug)) {
            return parent::showAction($request, $exception, $logger);
        }

        return new JsonResponse(null, $exception->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

In my project this returns `{}` with the appropriate HTTP response code in prod. Obviously your use-case might require different logic, which you can implement easily enough in your custom `ExceptionController::showAction()` method.

Hope this helps :)